# How to add contents of HTML file to page dynamically from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

From withing a Chrome extension, what's the best way to conditionally add the contents of an .html file to a page. Like you don't want to always add it, only if certain conditions are met. I see ways to conditionally inject script, but how can I conditionally add HTML from a file in the extension into the page?

If I have an option turned on, I want to add a block of code.

read option:

```
this.get_options = function ()
{
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        mytopics: true,
        friendtopics: true
    }, function(items) {
        self.settings = items;
        scan_page();
    });
}

this.scan_page = function()
{
    if (!(self.settings.mytopics || self.settings.friendtopics))
        return;
    // want to add in a decent amount of HTML from a file, here.
    // don't really want to construct it all via createnode calles
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out.

```
$('body').append('<div id="containerName"></div>');
$('#containerName').load(chrome.extension.getURL("markup/notification.html"));
```